# Failed to instantiate component or class "yii2tech\ar\softdelete\SoftDeleteBehavior"

Tags: error-message

Anyone knows what caused this error and how to fix it?

It appears when I edit a field or a section and try to save it.

[image]

```
Next yii\di\NotInstantiableException: Failed to instantiate component or class "yii2tech\ar\softdelete\SoftDeleteBehavior". in C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php:509
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(385): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('yii2tech\\ar\\sof...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(170): yii\di\Container->build('yii2tech\\ar\\sof...', Array, Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('yii2tech\\ar\\sof...', Array, Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(756): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(740): yii\base\Component->attachBehaviorInternal('softDelete', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(465): yii\base\Component->ensureBehaviors()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\base\Model.php(88): yii\base\Component->hasEventHandlers('init')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\BaseObject.php(109): craft\base\Model->init()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\base\Model.php(78): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\craftcms\commerce\src\services\OrderStatuses.php(151): craft\base\Model->__construct(Array)
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\craftcms\commerce\src\widgets\Orders.php(102): craft\commerce\services\OrderStatuses->getAllOrderStatuses()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\controllers\DashboardController.php(77): craft\commerce\widgets\Orders->getSettingsHtml()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\View.php(1558): craft\controllers\DashboardController->craft\controllers\{closure}()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\controllers\DashboardController.php(78): craft\web\View->namespaceInputs(Object(Closure), '__NAMESPACE__')
#14 [internal function]: craft\controllers\DashboardController->actionIndex()
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(178): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(552): yii\base\Controller->runAction('index', Array)
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(301): yii\base\Module->runAction('dashboard/index', Array)
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(103): craft\web\Application->runAction('dashboard/index', Array)
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(286): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(384): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\scoopsardooie\web\index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#23 {main} {"memory":37522080,"exception":"[object] (yii\\di\\NotInstantiableException(code: 0): Failed to instantiate component or class \"yii2tech\\ar\\softdelete\\SoftDeleteBehavior\". at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\scoopsardooie\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\di\\Container.php:509)
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by deleting my vendor files and reinstalling them  with composer install